# Grayscale in Fabric.js is slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, canvas, fabricjs

I don't think Fabric.js is the offender here, because when I add time alerts it only takes 2-3 seconds. However, here is the code it uses:

```
 applyTo: function(canvasEl) {
    var context = canvasEl.getContext('2d'),
        imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvasEl.width, canvasEl.height),
        data = imageData.data,
        len = imageData.width * imageData.height * 4,
        index = 0,
        average;

    while (index < len) {
      average = (data[index] + data[index + 1] + data[index + 2]) / 3;
      data[index]     = average;
      data[index + 1] = average;
      data[index + 2] = average;
      index += 4;
    }

    context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  },
```

So if it is not the offender, then the offender is the `putImageData` function.

Is there any way to increase/optimize that function so it works with a 5000x5000 image, in less than 15 seconds, of course?

If not, is there any way to set a "working" icon that only gets removed after the putImageData is finished through jQuery, because at the moment, it is removed after 2 seconds because the Fabric.js code finishes faster?

Comment: Do you need to be using JS and canvas for this, or could a [CSS approach](http://ethercycle.com/blog/index.php?entry=305&utm_content=buffer469a3&utm_source=buffer&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Buffer) work for your application?

Comment: The image that the user creates gets saved for future use and even printing, so I am guessing that this is the only way. I have greatly limited options and the image sizes so only special cases get that big. Think of it as creating a flyer for print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `putImageData` is taking the most time, you can't do much to improve its speed since it's a low-level function offered by the browser.

What you can do is process the image gradually and display it to the user without blocking the browser for 15 seconds straight.

Tip: instead of timing the execution of the script with *time alerts* I suggest just using Chrome Developer Tools. They have a great profiling tool for [javascript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/flame-chart) and, more specifically, [canvas drawing.](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/inspection/)

[image: Google Developer Tools Flame Chart]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with fabric.js but your options for making optimizations are very limited with the canvas. Putting your variables right after each other and not creating an average variable will save you a little bit of time:

```
data[index] = data[index+1] = data[index+2] = (data[index] + data[index + 1] + data[index + 2]) / 3;
index+=4;
```

As well you might want to try putting data on the canvas in rows. It won't speed things up but if you have such a large canvas it will be good to show the user some progress. In the following example I did this and changed your while loop into two for loops because I like for loops better :)

```
for(var i=0;i<imageData.height;i++) {
    var row = context.getImageData(0, i, canvasEl.width, 1);
    for(var j=0;j<imageData.width*4;j+=4) {
        row.data[index] = row.data[index+1] = row.data[index+2] = (row.data[index] + row.data[index + 1] + row.data[index + 2]) / 3;
        context.putImageData(row, 0, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Instead of getting/putting the image data once, you're doing it 5000×5000 more times, therefore likely slowing it down further. 2. Javascript will just execute the whole loop and **then** display the result entirely. To do what you want, you'd have elaborate/display the image in chuncks, over multiple frames, kind of like [FastDom's defer method](https://github.com/wilsonpage/fastdom#fastdomdeferframes-callback-context), using requestAnimationFrame